# Finding the domain of $ln(x-3)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the domain, in $\mathbb{R}$, of  $ln(x-3)^2$

To solve this I did:

- Since this is a logarithm, the input cannot be negative. Therefore, 
  $$(x-3)^2 > 0 \Leftrightarrow x - 3 > \sqrt{0} \Leftrightarrow x > 3$$

So the solution should be 
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 3\}$$ or
$$]3; +\infty [$$

But my book says the solution is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{3\}$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: (x-3)^2 is always greater than zero for all x other than 3 so your step is wrong. Obviously x can't be 3 as ln (0) is undefined. Hence the answer.

Comment: The notation used in the question is slightly ambiguous and this is the cause of your confusion. An extra pair of parentheses should have been used.

Comment: @user1892304 My thoughts exactly but this is how it was written on my book. It confused me as well so I thought you guys could shed some light one how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that solution of this inequation is  $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{3\}$ because  $$(x-3)^{ 2 }>0\quad $$ LHS is always positive except at $x=3$ point